# What's the essence of Jesus's teachings?

Tags: words-of-jesus, translation

Is it possible to discuss the nature of Jesus's teachings outside the context of Roman/English influence on biblical translation and transcription? In pondering the complexities that evolve from passing a religious teaching through two cultures of imperialism and colonization, over multiple centuries, I'm seeking a smaller than bite-sized morsel. A potent distillate of Jesus's message. Thoughts? Sources?

Comment: this seems kind of vague. Are you looking for the smallest summary of Jesus' teachings like 'Love the Lord and thy neighbor' or 'faith, repentance, baptism'?

Comment: Apologies - I don't intend to be vague. I am not looking for the smallest summary, necessarily ... I'll see if I can find better wording.

Comment: One way to distill the essence of Jesus's teachings is that **He frees us from the bondage of sin to enable us do love the Lord and our neighbor, and to enter heaven (the Kingdom of God)**.  Another short one: **"Jesus enables us to be spiritually healthy, the *genuine* option in contrast to other religions / spiritualities."**  Of course there is A LOT to unpack.  But by distilling the whole Bible into a few sentences you risk distorting the message.  Compare with trying to distill a textbook on nutrition to a few sentences on how to eat healthy.

Comment: Have you tried John 3:16? Also, I think most people (and biblical translators, in particular) will disagree with, and perhaps even be offended by, the notion that Christian teachings are substantially influenced by "two cultures of imperialism and colonization".

Comment: Matthew the second part of your comment gets closer to what I am seeking ... I don't mind suggesting that the Roman and British Empires substantially influenced the way Christianity developed, and I think it's worth exploring without taking offense. With that context in mind, I'm wondering what the root teachings might sound like outside the institution of the Church, were I to have 15 minutes on a park bench with a living (i.e. pre-crucifixion) Jesus, what might that simple message be like. (hopefully more understandable)

Comment: have you read any of the bible?

Comment: Yes I have read the Bible.

Comment: Sorry, but how to reduce Jesus's teachings to a "smaller than bite-sized morsel" is very much a matter of opinion. To be so reductionistic you must cut important things out.

Comment: @curiousdannii it's unfortunate that your singular perspective, and lack of curiosity, resulted in this question being closed. It's not opinion based. But your rationale for closing the question IS simply opinion based. A very Whitman-esque contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering what the root teachings might sound like outside the institution of the Church, were I to have 15 minutes on a park bench with a living (i.e. pre-crucifixion) Jesus, what might that simple message be like.

One short clarification before my answer: It would have been the **post-resurrection** Jesus (not pre-crucifixion), since Jesus is alive today!  This is how Jesus appeared to Thomas or to Paul.

The 15 minutes "elevator pitch" would be a **PERSONAL ENCOUNTER** in substance (teaching is embedded in it).  The encounter will include the following points:

1. **Authenticate himself** as the true Jesus, since He is also God who knows you inside out, past/present/future.  If necessary, provide you a sign so you believe who He claims to be.
2. If you are drawn to him, his look and attitude would be inviting, with love and compassion.  You will feel refreshed.  Although you will feel sorrow for your past sins, you will be overjoyed by his invitation (like the [Zacchaeus story](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2019%3A1-10&version=NLT)) and will voluntarily offer to make it up to people you have wronged in the past.
3. He would **ask you "What do you want?"** (so you are aware of your deepest desire) but proceed to give you what you really need (since He is living water, bread of life, etc.).
4. He would answer your questions instead of preaching, but would most likely **inserted the basics among your questions** such as:

   - who he is (God, Savior, King)
   - what he has done for you (frees us from bondage of sin through his crucifixion), and
   - his wish for you (communicated as a best friend would, or as the most loving father would).
5. He would **issue you a challenge** to become his disciple and follow him after the 15 minutes is over, giving you instruction on what to do:

   - join a church, since it's through His Body (his brothers and sisters) that the full teaching is taught, the love is expressed, and (for some denominations) the graces are partially dispensed (through the sacraments).
   - read the whole Bible, since that's the best means to understand His character and His work among humans (He came down from heaven, did his mission, and went back to heaven again).

   The challenge is not threatening, nor cajoling, nor selling, but a choice that fully respects your freedom after your mind has been cleared in the past few minutes.
6. If you accept the challenge, **He will breathe his Holy Spirit to you** so for the rest of your life, He can be present with you everywhere you go within your heart, guiding you, giving grace to you, pray for you, console you, etc.  He will be your best friend in spirit.

Comment: @whakawaehere I updated and polished the answer.  Please comment here if this still doesn't answer your question.